# Estimating Poisson regression marginal effects manualy

Tags: self-study, poisson-regression

How can I estimate marginal effects of a Poisson distribution manually, without using the `margins` comand in Stata.

Like for example:

```
poisson kids educ age black

Iteration 0:   log likelihood = -2101.1772  
Iteration 1:   log likelihood = -2101.1771  

Poisson regression                              Number of obs     =      1,129
                                                LR chi2(3)        =      84.90
                                                Prob > chi2       =     0.0000
Log likelihood = -2101.1771                     Pseudo R2         =     0.0198

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        kids |      Coef.   Std. Err.      z    P>|z|     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
        educ |  -.0483602   .0068249    -7.09   0.000    -.0617368   -.0349836
         age |   .0089042   .0030858     2.89   0.004     .0028562    .0149522
       black |   .2723359   .0576417     4.72   0.000     .1593602    .3853116
       _cons |   1.199105   .1682269     7.13   0.000     .8693863    1.528824
------------------------------------------------------------------------------



. margins, at(educ=12 age=32)

Predictive margins                              Number of obs     =      1,129
Model VCE    : OIM

Expression   : Predicted number of events, predict()
at           : educ            =          12
               age             =          32

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
             |            Delta-method
             |     Margin   Std. Err.      z    P>|z|     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
       _cons |   2.539273   .1043065    24.34   0.000     2.334836     2.74371
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

How can I get the `_cons` value of 2.539273 shown above manually (by hand/calculator)? How does Stata calculate that value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code predicts the number of children using the estimated coefficients as if everyone in your data had their own actual race, but were 32 years old and only finished high school.

My coefficients match, but the margins number is slightly different for some reason (might be a Stata version difference, but should work on your end):

```
. quietly bcuse fertil1, clear

. poisson kids educ age black, nolog

Poisson regression                              Number of obs     =      1,129
                                                LR chi2(3)        =      84.90
                                                Prob > chi2       =     0.0000
Log likelihood = -2101.1771                     Pseudo R2         =     0.0198

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        kids |      Coef.   Std. Err.      z    P>|z|     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
        educ |  -.0483602   .0068249    -7.09   0.000    -.0617368   -.0349836
         age |   .0089042   .0030858     2.89   0.004     .0028562    .0149522
       black |   .2723359   .0576417     4.72   0.000     .1593602    .3853116
       _cons |   1.199105   .1682269     7.13   0.000     .8693863    1.528824
------------------------------------------------------------------------------

. margins, at(educ=12 age=32)

Predictive margins                              Number of obs     =      1,129
Model VCE    : OIM

Expression   : Predicted number of events, predict()
at           : educ            =          12
               age             =          32

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
             |            Delta-method
             |     Margin   Std. Err.      z    P>|z|     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
       _cons |   2.534472   .1040815    24.35   0.000     2.330476    2.738468
------------------------------------------------------------------------------

. generate double pred_kids = exp(_b[_cons] + _b[age]*32 + _b[educ]*12 + _b[black]*black)  

. sum pred_kids

    Variable |        Obs        Mean    Std. Dev.       Min        Max
-------------+---------------------------------------------------------
   pred_kids |      1,129    2.534472    .2156485   2.468761   3.241552
```

If you want to do it by calculator, you can do something like this with a weighted average:

```
. tab black

      black |      Freq.     Percent        Cum.
------------+-----------------------------------
          0 |      1,033       91.50       91.50
          1 |         96        8.50      100.00
------------+-----------------------------------
      Total |      1,129      100.00

. display exp(_b[_cons] + _b[age]*32 + _b[educ]*12 + _b[black]*1)*96/1129 + exp(_b[_cons] + _b[age]*32 + _b[educ]*12 + _b[black]*0)*1033/1129  
2.5344722
```

Obviously, you will need to type the actual coefficients since your calculator does not know about them.

`bcuse` may need to be installed from SSC to run the code:

```
quietly bcuse fertil1, clear
poisson kids educ age black, nolog
margins, at(educ=12 age=32)
generate double pred_kids = exp(_b[_cons] + _b[age]*32 + _b[educ]*12 + _b[black]*black)  
sum pred_kids
tab black
display exp(_b[_cons] + _b[age]*32 + _b[educ]*12 + _b[black]*1)*96/1129 + exp(_b[_cons] + _b[age]*32 + _b[educ]*12 + _b[black]*0)*1033/1129
```